# why a heap node of index i (starting from 1) and its height h satisfy (2^h)*i <= n < (2^(h+1)*i) where n is the heap size?

Tags: heap

why a heap node of index i (starting from 1) and its height h satisfy (2^h)*i <= n < (2^(h+1)*i) where n is the heap size?

Answer (score 0):

Case N:1

```
2^h <= 1 <= 2^(h+1)
```

Note height of node is log(n) = log(1) = 0

```
= 2^0 <= 1 <= 2^(0+1) 
= 1 <= 1 <= 2
```

So you can see its true for case n = 1

Let replace h = log(n) into the original question

```
= 2^h <= n <= 2^(h+1)
= 2^(log(n)) <= n <= 2^(log(n)+1)   #replace n = log(n)
= n <= n <= 2^log(n) * 2^1   #exponents property
= n <= n <= 2n
```

Note the index 'i' cancels out if we divide by 'i' on each side.

Comment: I don't want to proof it, I want to know how to find that expression. what clue to that.